# Refresh frames in html page

Tags: php, javascript, html

A very simple question. I have a html page which is divided into three frames, which actually show three html pages like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A simple frameset document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%" border="5">
<FRAMESET rows="100, 200" border="5">
  <FRAME src="abc.html">
  <FRAME src="xyz.html">
</FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="ijk.html">
<NOFRAMES>
  <P>This frameset document contains:
  <UL>
     <li>some text</li>
  </UL>
</NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

What I need is a powerful refresh button (can be backed by JS/PHP/etc.) on each page, so that pages can be refreshed on button click and independently, and refreshing one page does not impact other. Is this a possibility? A sample code (that i want) for one of the pages in the frames (say abc.html) can be like:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='123.jpg'><br />
<input type="button" Onclick="refresh">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function refresh,write

```
window.location.reload()
```

Comment: use `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
document.frames[i].location.reload();
```